# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

getting error while transferring value from one hbase table to other

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1410946588060_0019_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.write(TableOutputFormat.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:576)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

My driver class:

```
  Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

     // define scan and define column families to scan
     Scan scan = new Scan();
     scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"));

    // Job job = new Job(conf,"ExampleSummary");
     Job job =Job.getInstance(conf); 

        job.setJarByClass(HBaseDriver.class);
        //
     // define input hbase tableS
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
         "test1",
            scan,
            HBaseMapper.class,
            ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
            Result.class,
            job);
     // define output table
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
          "test2",
          HBaseReducer.class, 
          job);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

My mapper:

```
 public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable rowKey, Result columns, Context context)
   throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    try {
           // get rowKey and convert it to string
           String inKey = new String(rowKey.get());
           // set new key having only date
           String oKey = inKey.split("#")[0];
           // get sales column in byte format first and then convert it to string (as it is stored as string from hbase shell)
           byte[] bSales = columns.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("sales"));
           String sSales = new String(bSales);
           Integer sales = new Integer(sSales);
           // emit date and sales values
           context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(oKey.getBytes()), new IntWritable(sales));

          } catch (RuntimeException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

My reducer:

```
 public void reduce(ImmutableBytesWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
           throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          try {

           int sum = 0;
           // loop through different sales vales and add it to sum
           for (IntWritable sales : values) {
            Integer intSales = new Integer(sales.toString());
            sum += intSales;
           } 

           // create hbase put with rowkey as date


           Put insHBase = new Put(key.get());
           // insert sum value to hbase 
           insHBase.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("sum"), Bytes.toBytes(sum));
           // write data to Hbase table
           context.write(null, insHBase);

          } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution,just have to change

this:

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
     "test1",
        scan,
        HBaseMapper.class,
        ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
        Result.class,
        job);
```

to this:

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
     "test1",
        scan,
        HBaseMapper.class,
        ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
        IntWritable.class,
        job);
```